# How to modify pydantic field when another one is changed?

Tags: python, validation, decorator, fastapi, pydantic

I have a pydantic class such as:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class Programmer(BaseModel):
    python_skill: float
    stackoverflow_skill: float
    total_score: float = None
```

Now I am calculating the total_score according to the other fields:

```
@validator("total_score", always=True)
def calculat_total_score(cls, v, *, values):
    return values.get("python_skill") + values.get("stackoverflow_skill")
```

This works fine, but now when I change one of the skills:

```
programmer = Programmer(python_skill=1.0, stackoverflow_skill=9.0)
print(programmer.total_score) # return 10.0
programmer.python_skill=2.0 
print(programmer.total_score) # still return 10.0
```

I would like the total_score to automatically update.

Any solutions?
TNX!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [root validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators) for this. It is called after every update. Like so:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator, root_validator


class Programmer(BaseModel):
    python_skill: float
    stackoverflow_skill: float
    total_score: float = None

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True

    @root_validator
    def calculate_total_score(cls, values):
        values["total_score"] = values.get("python_skill") + values.get("stackoverflow_skill")
        return values


programmer = Programmer(python_skill=1.0, stackoverflow_skill=9.0)
print(programmer.total_score)  # 10.0
programmer.python_skill = 2.0
print(programmer.total_score)  # 11.0
```

*Note: There was a [bug](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1971) in the versions before 1.7.3, so I recommend updating*